# Why does this thermodynamics problem seem to have two answers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

The problem goes as:
For an ideal gas, molar heat capacity varies as: $C = C_v + aV$, where $a$ is a constant.
Now we are asked to find a relation between Temperature and Volume.

The way I approached the problem is by comparing the general expression for the heat capacity of an ideal gas to this one.
The general expression is: $C = C_v +\frac{R}{1-n} $ where $n$ is the coefficient in the general polytropic process.
By comparing the two equations, we can say that:

$\frac{R}{1-n} = aV$
Also, we know that $TV^{n-1} = k$, where $k$ is a constant.
So we can just replace $n-1$ in the second equation get a relation as: $TV^{-\frac{R}{aV}} = k$. But that is not the answer, and that is what I cannot understand. What went wrong here?
The method to get the 'correct' answer is:
$TV^{n-1}=k$
$\Rightarrow$
$T(n-1)dV + VdT = 0$
$\Rightarrow$
$(1-n)=\frac{VdT}{TdV} = \frac{R}{aV}$

$\Rightarrow \int \frac{dT}{T} = \int\frac{RdV}{aV^2}$

$\Rightarrow ln(T) = -\frac{R}{aV} + k'$

$\Rightarrow T=e^{-\frac{R}{aV}+k'}$

 This is more of a mathematical question, But I couldn't boil down this thermodynamics problem into a math problem, and I guess there is a chance of physics being involved here and there. 
So why is the second answer correct? And what is wrong in the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397215/247238) SE post,
$$C=C_V+P\frac{dV}{dT}$$
where we have taken the number of moles to be one. Comparing with the expression given
$$P\frac{dV}{dT}=aV\Rightarrow \frac{1}{aV^2}dV=\frac{1}{RT}dT$$
Integratin leads to

$$T=T_0e^{-R/aV}$$
As required. The way you have done is valid only for polytropic process no in general.

---

A Polytropic process is the one which follows:
$$pV^n=C$$
which is not general. A general process for an ideal gas defined as
$$p=f(V)$$
For example, the process might be like
$$p=V^3+V^2 e^{-\lambda V}$$
which is not polytropic!

Comment: But isn't a polytropic process the general process? From what I know, you can define every sort of process from that form. If that is true, I still do not understand why using R/(1-n) instead of that work bit breaks down, even though it is the same expression, just manipulated a bit

Comment: @archmundada See the edit.

Comment: that really cleared things up, thanks a lot!