# Heat Capacity of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics

The question is:

A monoatomic gas undergoes a process $PV^3=k$ where k is a constant. Find the heat capacity of the gas.

Problem:

I know how to calculate the heat capacity at constant pressure ($C_p$) and ($C_v$) of a gas but this problem does not ask any of them.

I came to know about this formula:

For a process $PV^n=k$,  $C = (\frac{1}{\gamma - 1}-\frac{1}{n-1})R$

as the solution but found no proof or anything. How can I start to prove it myself?

Comment: Appears to be answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68280/what-is-the-deal-with-heat-capacity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $PV^n=k$, then $$P=\frac{P_0V_0^n}{V^n}$$and $$PdV=\frac{P_0V_0^n}{V^n}dV=-\frac{P_0V_0^n}{(n-1)}d\left(\frac{1}{V^{n-1}}\right)$$So,
$$\int_{V_0}^V{PdV}=\frac{P_0V_0^n}{(n-1)}\left[\frac{1}{V_0^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{V^{n-1}}\right]=\frac{P_0V_0^n}{(n-1)}\left[\frac{V_0}{V_0^{n}}-\frac{V}{V^{n}}\right]=\frac{P_0V_0-PV}{(n-1)}$$From this, it follows that, for this particular process path $$PdV=-\frac{d(PV)}{(n-1)}=-\frac{RdT}{(n-1)}$$So, from the first law:  $$dU=C_vdT=dQ+\frac{RdT}{(n-1)}$$So,
$$dQ=\left[C_v-\frac{R}{(n-1)}\right]dT$$
The authors refer to the term in brackets as the "heat capacity," but it should not really be considered heat capacity, since, in thermodynamics, we regard heat capacity is a fundamental physical property of the gas (independent of process path).

Comment: Then what should the quantity be called??

Comment: I wouldn't ascribe a name to it.  They do, but, in my judgment, this is a mistake which only serves to confuse the student (as it has done to you).

Comment: I think it makes sense because we also define $C_p$ and $C_v$ in a similar fashion. So calling this heat capacity for this process makes sense.

Comment: It’s okay for you to tentatively accept this, but please bear in mind my comment about the desirsbility of heat capacity being regarded as a function of state rather than path.  That’s why we define Cv as the partial of U with respect to T, and Cp as the partial of H with respect to T.